# eassist-function-tags: Invalid function: semantic-find-tags-by-class

Tags: emacs, cedet

I　got this problem when I using function "eassist-list-methods",

```
eassist-function-tags: Invalid function: semantic-find-tags-by-class
```

can you help me to solve it?
I use the newest cedet-devel version
emacs version is:24.2

Answer (score 1):

http://sourceforge.net/p/cedet/mailman/message/30564469/

I stuck a: (require 'semantic/find) in there which should fix up those problems. If any other unknown functions show up, just grep for it in the lisp/cedet/ package somewhere (assume anything starting w/ semantic- is in the semantic package, for example) and then add said require to eassist.

```
<pre>
diff -Naur eassist.el.orig eassist.el
--- eassist.el.orig 2015-08-11 11:03:58.544695143 +0800
+++ eassist.el  2015-08-11 10:59:17.456679391 +0800
@@ -103,6 +103,7 @@
 ;;; Code:

 (require 'semantic)
+(require 'semantic/find)

 ;; ================================== My STRING utils ========================
 (defun eassist-string-without-last (string n)

</pre>
```

The function semantic-find-tags-by-class is a macro, so you will 
need to recompile eassist with the patch I provided last time.  That 
should end up solving the problem.

You could do that by opening eassist.el, and doing

M-x byte-compile-file RET

and then:

M-x load-library RET eassist RET

You can try this:
https://github.com/liugang/taglist

The taglist plugin is a source code browser plugin for Emacs and provides an overview of the structure of the programming language files